# Should I "migrate" an answer to another SE site?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Not understanding that it was (possibly) inappropriate, I asked a question on Physics SE that was very similar to a question that I had already asked on Aviation SE.

Now that I understand that it was (possibly) inappropriate, should I delete the question to Physics SE?

I don't want to disrespect the author of the one answer that was received.

Also, I don't want to lose the information content of the answer.

What should I do now?

Would it be permissible to copy the answer and post it verbatim, fully attributed as to who wrote it and in what part of SE it was originally posted, as an answer to my very similar question in ASE, along with a note that the question to which it was posted was slightly different from the one in ASE?  And then delete the question from PSE?  (I would ***not*** "migrate" the answer without deleting the question from PSE.)

Or what other course of action should I take?

In case it matters, I did note in the question that I had asked a similar question on ASE-- and provided a link to it-- looking at the edit history it appears that I added this note a few hours after the sole answer had been posted, and about three hours after I posted the question.

This is the question -- [Is this vector diagram of the forces at play in turning flight correct?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/548011/is-this-vector-diagram-of-the-forces-at-play-in-turning-flight-correct)

This is the one answer that has been posted as of yet -- [Is this vector diagram of the forces at play in turning flight correct?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/548011/is-this-vector-diagram-of-the-forces-at-play-in-turning-flight-correct/548030#548030)

Or should I just chalk it up to experience and leave the question and answer on PSE to stand? That would be my preference-- would that be acceptable?

I don't know if this is relevant or not, but the question was poorly-received on ASE.  But I have no wish to delete the question from ASE.  I feel that it highlights a significant flaw in the current flight training curriculum.

Of course, if the moderators at one site notify me that the question on the other site ***must*** be deleted or the other one will be, that would open up another can of worms, and I suppose I would delete the one from the PSE site.  (While "migrating" the answer as described above, unless the consensus is that that would not be ethical or appropriate.)  Likewise, in an even more extreme case where the ASE question were simply deleted by moderators as a duplicate of the PSE question, I suppose I would then delete the PSE question and re-post the ASE question. But, it has not come to any of that yet, and I have no particular reason to think that it will.

So the current question is, as things stand right now, from the standpoint of the PSE community, is it best that I delete the PSE question, and if so (or if I am essentially forced to delete one of the questions by action of the ASE community, and choose to delete the PSE question), is it alright to "migrate" the one answer that it has received, in the manner described above?

Additional notes-- I do understand that questions considered to be duplicates of another question ***on the same site*** normally get closed, not deleted.  However since I did receive a note from an ASE user (not a moderator) saying I ought to delete one of the questions, I was trying think of what best to do to not lose the answer that was posted.

At least one answer to this meta question has suggested that the PSE question should be migrated to ASE, where it would undoubtedly be closed as a duplicate, but not deleted, unless moderators decided to take some unusual action for some reason.

My current inclination is just to leave it alone and disregard the one note I received (from an ASE user who was not a moderator) saying that one of the questions ought to be deleted, but avoid asking such similar questions in the future now that I understand SE policy and philosophy better.  If moderators of either site let me know that this is not acceptable, then I'll consider "migrating" the answer as described above and deleting the PSE question.

Answer (score 1):

What I actually think would be best, *if* you can pull it off (and I don't claim to know whether this is possible), is to make the two questions distinct from each other by editing each of them to be more specific to its respective site. There's no problem with posting two slightly different questions about essentially the same topic to two different sites; you can have a question here on Physics SE that focuses on the fundamental science aspects of the situation you're considering, while your question on Aviation SE could focus on its applications to airplanes and/or aerodynamics.

However, if you're going to do that, you have to make your edits in such a way that it doesn't invalidate any existing answers on each site. That's a requirement we have based on courtesy to the people who put in the time to write answers for you.

If it's not practical to do that, then you have some other options. For one thing, as you suggested:

> Would it be permissible to copy the answer and post it verbatim, fully attributed as to who wrote it and in what part of SE it was originally posted, as an answer to my very similar question in ASE, along with a note that the question to which it was posted was slightly different from the one in ASE? And then delete the question from PSE?

If it were going in the other direction, then yes, it would definitely be *permissible* to do that (although it's a different matter whether it would be well received by the community). Content here is licensed under a Creative Commons license which allows, among other things, copying the content to another site where it will be distributed under the same license. And our rules on plagiarism simply require that content be appropriately quoted and attributed, but they don't prevent copying. We do frown on making an answer *entirely* out of copied content, but this is sort of a special case since the answer was written for that question, just in a different venue.

Since you would be copying from Physics SE to Aviation SE and making the copied post on the latter site, it'd really be up to the Aviation community whether this would be allowed by their norms.

As another option, you could ask the Aviation mods whether they'd be willing to migrate the question here. Then we could merge it into the Physics version.

Or, it might also be reasonable to just leave things as they are. While it's true that in principle we shouldn't fragment the answers between the two questions, it's just *one* question, and not one that's drawing a lot of attention either, so any harm that may be done by having it in two places is limited in this case.

Comment: "Or, it might also be reasonable to just leave things as they are. While it's true that in principle we shouldn't fragment the answers between the two questions, it's just one question, and not one that's drawing a lot of attention either, so any harm that may be done by having it in two places is limited in this case." -- as of now I am leaning toward this, just leaving it alone.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but it requires a bit of central planning as all great solutions do ;)

I am not sure if you're aware of this but users who can cast close votes can also cast votes to migrate a question as a whole (along with its answers, comments, revisions, everything) to another StackExchange site. So, I'd suggest you not to delete your question on your own, after all, it is probably fit for the site if not enough users with $\text{>3k}$ reputation feel that there is no need for migration. And, if it is not a good fit, probably enough users with $\text{>3k}$ reputation will vote to migrate your question.

If the question gets migrated to Aviation SE, the ball is then in the court of Aviation SE users. If they think that the migrated question is a duplicate of the existing question of yours on Aviation SE, they will mark it as a duplicate of the same. This way, you wouldn't have any of the content, either yours or of those who answered, erased while the questions would be in their appropriate places and linked via a duplication link if they are indeed duplicates of each other.

On your part, bringing this up on Meta is good enough IMO. You have already linked to the Meta posts on your question. As I mentioned, I'd suggest against deleting the question on your own.

---

**Edit**

Unfortunately, only moderators can migrate questions to Aviation SE it seems, not all users who can cast close votes. So, the rest of my answer is still valid IMO but I'd add that since the migration to Aviation SE requires direct moderator intervention, it'd be a good practice to make sure the question belongs here beforehand ;)

Comment: The thing is there is already a very similar question on ASE -- the one I asked earlier-- there's a link to it in the PSE question-- so the PSE question would be immediately closed as a duplicate if it were migrated to ASE.  I had to fight hard for the ASE question (including several rounds of edits) as some people voted that it was a duplicate of OTHER questions on ASE.  So migrating the QUESTION to ASE would not be a wise move in my opinion.

Comment: @quietflyer Questions are not deleted as duplicates. They're marked duplicates. And I don't see anything problematic with that if your question is "very similar".

Comment: You are right, duplicates are not deleted, they just get closed.  Which would not lose the answer that was posted, but deprive anyone else the chance to answer.  Or the other ASE question might be closed, depriving anyone else the chance to answer it.  My preference would be just to leave the question alone but you are right that moving to ASE would not actually cause it to be deleted.  It would annoy the ASE community though or at those who think I ask too many questions on topics related to anything to do with sideslips, centrifugal force, etc and tend to heavily downvote those questions.

Comment: @quiteflyer And it's a good thing because you don't want answers to the same question scattered all around. I don't know why you want to keep both your questions open anyway if they're very similar. And even if both are closed because they're both dupes of some other question, what's the issue? Again, you don't want to have answers to the same question posted in different places. If your question is how do I keep my question open even if it's a duplicate, I'm glad to say that there is no way to do so as there shouldn't be!

Comment: @DvijDC -- When I originally asked, I didn't realize that it was not considered good practice to ask essentially the same question of different communities.  I wanted to get the perspective of a fresh group of people who might look at the problem in a different, and more scientifically rigorous, manner.  The question had no received answers in ASE that were not downvoted.  The question itself was downvoted in ASE.  I wanted the perspective of a different community.  But now that I understand SE better I will try to make questions more clearly different.  And maybe they actually are...

Comment: @DvijDC -- and perhaps they are different enough as is even in this case.

Comment: @quietflyer OK, I see. If you want to have different perspectives, editing the way DavidZ suggested looks like the best way to go. All the best! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a good way to edit to make the questions more different at this point without changing the PSE question so substantially that it invalidates the existing answer or at least makes it kind irrelevant to what the modified question would be.  Perhaps they are different enough already, perhaps not.

I don't feel that actually migrating the question to ASE, so that it could be closed there as a duplicate (while preserving the one answer that was received) would be viewed as a positive step by the ASE community.  Questions on topics such as these tend to be downvoted on ASE, or at least that's been the recent trend.  If PSE moderators see fit to do that, then so be it, but I'm not advocating that at present.

My current inclination is just to leave it alone and disregard the one note I received (from an ASE user who was not a moderator) saying that one of the questions ought to be deleted, but I'll avoid asking such similar questions in the future now that I understand SE policy and philosophy better. If moderators of either site let me know that this is not acceptable, then I'll consider "migrating" the answer as described in this meta question, and deleting the PSE question.  The point is well taken, from another answer, that before doing so I should first consider whether this is acceptable by the standards of the ASE community, perhaps by asking a question on that Meta site.